# how to validate a varchar data of 2 years separated by a hyphen on SQL DB

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, validation, date

I have this table

```
create table periodo (
codigo_p varchar(9)not null,
fecha_inicial date not null,
fecha_final date not null, 
estatus char (10) not null constraint chk_estatus check (estatus in ('activo','inactivo')), primary key (codigo_p)
 );
```

there is some data

```
codigo_p  | fecha_inicial | fecha_final |  estatus
-----------+---------------+-------------+------------
 2017-2018 | 2003-08-08    | 2003-08-07  | inactivo   ---> bad
 2018-2019 | 2018-09-15    | 2019-06-05  | activo     ---> good
```

The problem that I have, is how I validate the correct insertion of the codigo_p, fecha_inicial and fecha_final data?

1. how I validate that in codigo_p there is two consecutives years and a hyphen in between
2. how I validate that the dates on fecha_inicial and fecha_final are inside of the time period that codigo_p represents

I'm working with postgresql, I need my bd secure, I hope there is other solution than validating with a javacript  and a HTML code in the front-end of my web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

Basicaly the solution is on the constraint i made four (4) of then:

Let me explein the context of this proyect, i'm doing a data base for a non-american school, and they manage the time of each  academic "year" with 2 years due to  the school start in september and end in july, so, there are 2 years envolve, and they manage the  academic "year" with this code: 2017-2018

So i was searching for a wey to validate the correct insertion of that code in the codigo_p row, also, my fecha_inicial (represents the starting day) and my fecha_final (represents the final day) both of then need to have the same year as the codigo_p years.

And this is the solution:

---

1. One for validate that the first date is lower that the next one, because whe are working in a period of time in the future and not in the past.
2. this on, takes the first 4 char of codigo_p and compares it with the extracted year from fecha_inicial

3.this on, takes the last 4 char of codigo_p and compares it with the extracted year from fecha_final

4.and this one checks if the hyphen is in his position on codigo_p

there is the SQL code

```
create table periodo (
codigo_p char(9)not null, 
fecha_inicial date not null,
fecha_final date not null, 
estatus char (10) not null constraint chk_estatus check (estatus in ('activo','inactivo')),
constraint chk_fecha check  (fecha_inicial < fecha_final),
constraint chk_codigo check ( (SUBSTRING (codigo_p,1,4)) = (cast ( (extract (year from fecha_inicial)) as varchar))  ),
constraint chk_codigo2 check ( (SUBSTRING (codigo_p,6,4)) = (cast ( (extract (year from fecha_final)) as varchar))  ),
constraint chk_codigo3 check ( (SUBSTRING (codigo_p,5,1)) = '-'     ),
primary key (codigo_p)
 );
```

I really hope this helps to some one, this is my first question and answer in this page, thanks to all.

Sorry is there is some grammar error, english is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic I would use.  You can convert it to code.

First, convert the string in codigo_p to 2 date variables.  A value of `2017-2018` would have variables of `2017-01-01` and `2018-12-31`.

Then it's simple date comparison.  Check to see if the other two fields are between those two values.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each component of the code:

```
select (case when not (codigo_p ~ '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$' and
                       left(codigo_p, 4)::int = right(codgo_p, 4)::int - 1
                      )
             then 'bad'
             when left(codigo_p, 4)::int >= extract(year from fecha_inicial) and
                  left(codigo_p, 4)::int >= extract(year from fecha_final) and
                  right(codigo_p, 4)::int >= extract(year from fecha_inicial) and
                  right(codigo_p, 4)::int >= extract(year from fecha_final)
             then 'good'
             else 'bad'
        end)
from . . .
```

Comment: This code help me to watch what i could do with SQL funtions that i don't know there exist, Thanks